# MVC5 model grouping results incorrectly

Tags: linq, visual-studio-2013, lambda, sql-server-2008-r2, asp.net-mvc-5

MVC5 intranet site. One view has two datasets being sent to the view. This displays the data correctly. But the data is 'wrong'.
Here is the c# code

```
 List<object> myList = new List<object>();
        myList.Add(db.hw_poapp_VoucherDetail_vw.Where(a => a.trx_ctrl_num == id).ToList());
        myList.Add(db.hw_poapp_VoucherDetailNotes_vw.Where(a => a.trx_ctrl_num == id).ToList());
        // try this incase it's a Lambda thing
        var notes = from d in db.hw_poapp_VoucherDetailNotes_vw
                    where d.trx_ctrl_num == id
                    select d;

        return View(myList);
```

I can use SQL profiler to catch the SQL being used and run it in SQL management studio to return the results as

```
trx_ctrl_num        invoice_link           note
VO205164            X:\SOME.pdf            Note 1
VO205164            X:\XXXXX12345.txt      Note 1
VO205164            X:\Tiny 2.jpg          Note 1
```

A single transaction has three links attached, each link has a note

When I debug the c#, the results are not as expected.
Debugging the second list (or the var note out of desperation) I expect 3 distinct results, but it appears because the 'Note' field is identical, the three results are identical.
i.e. three results but all of the first line from the results.
If the 'note' field contains unique data, then the lines get put into the list as expected
See the attached jpg for screen dumps of the debug
[From Debugging code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffHum.jpg)

The model class I'm getting data for looks like this

```
public partial class hw_poapp_VoucherDetailNotes_vw
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Voucher No:")]
    public string trx_ctrl_num { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Voucher Link")]
    public string invoice_link { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Note:")]
    public string note { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried with and without key value
So, in summary, the SQL that gets run selects the correct data.
The List, whether using Lambda or LINQ only has the first line repeated three times
The view correctly displays the bad data.
Any help gratefully received

Comment: what is the table setup for the notes? does it have the transaction id?

Comment: The view I am looking at is from a single table. Just for fun(?) I changed the view to  _select 'VO205164' trx_ctrl_num, 'link 1' invoice_link,'' note
 union
 select 'VO205164' trx_ctrl_num, 'link 2' invoice_link,'' note
 union
 select 'VO205164' trx_ctrl_num, 'link 3' invoice_link,''  note_. And the result was the same, the SQL that gets generated from MVC and captured through SQL Profiler and run in SQL management Studio returns the expected results, but the data model repeats the first link. Please note, this is looking at an old existing database

Comment: FYI, I changed the View to a Stored Procedure, and this gets the data correctly and it's displayed on the view form correctly. I will try and update to Visual Studio 2015 and see if that makes a change

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it was all down to the Entity Keys on the model.
I opened the *.edmx diagram and right clicked on each of the three fields of this view and set them to Entity Key ticked to create a unique key. I thought doing this in the Model Class would do this; my inexperience.
Re-built the project and now it runs OK. This 'Entity Key' does not change the model class in any way, just the edmx file (it appears). However, I guess because the key I had (trx_ctrl_num) was not unique across the three records, it got "confused".
Thanks